# match in rails routes.rb is redirecting too many times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a route that is suppose to match something like this
localhost:3000/site/admin

and redirect to

localhost:3000/en/site/admin

here is the route line that should match this
routes.rb

```
match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
```

but instead of matching it and redirecting to localhost:3000/en/site/admin, It's redirecting infite to this

```
http://localhost:3000/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/site/admin
(adds /en until browser complains about infite loop)
```

Any idea why this infite loops is happening? Thanks

***EDIT***

Link to my my entire routes.rb file

https://gist.github.com/2323762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a route higher up in the file that catches the "/:locale/:path" URL that you're redirecting to? If not, your route will fall through and be caught once again by the "*path" route (which matches anything).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense i'll check that out. I also posted a gist to my routes.rb file

Comment: Since `sites` is a resource, and `admin` is defined on `collection`, the URL is `sites/admin`, not `site/admin` (defining them on `member` would give you something like `site/1/admin`).

Comment: One other thing: you might add a catch-all route to the bottom of the `scope ":locale"` block, so that as long as you start your URL with a valid locale, e.g. `/en`, you won't get an infinite redirect.

Comment: One *final* thing: The `*path` route needs to be the very last one; since it literally matches anything, any routes below it will never be executed.

Comment: Alright great. I was trying to locate site/admin but it's sites/admin like you said. I'll have to fix that naming. Would the catch-all route prevent it from doing that to a user if they were to type it wrong? I don't want a user accidently typing /site/admin and getting the /en/en/en/ link. I'll move that to the very last one, thanks so much for your quick help.

Comment: Yeah; by creating a catch all route at the very bottom of the `scope` block, you can have URLs like `/any_valid_locale/anything/whatever` and they won't get infinite redirects as the first part is a valid locale. Also `/invalid_url` would get redirected to `/default_locale/invalid_url` and then get caught by that route, again keeping infinite redirects away.

Comment: Rats, I thought that it had fixed it, but I guess not. I moved it to the bottom but it still re-directs indefinitely. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052158/why-rails-app-is-redirecting-unexpectedly-instead-of-matching-the-route)