# Why rails app is redirecting unexpectedly instead of matching the route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I asked this question earlier and thought it was fixed, but it's not. Previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050148/match-in-rails-routes-rb-is-redirecting-too-many-times)

My problem is I am trying to set my routes so that when I type in

localhost:3000/sites/admin

It *should* redirect to

localhost:3000/en/sites/admin

here is my routes.rb file

```
scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", as: "log_out"
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", as: "log_in"

  resources :sites, except: [:new, :edit, :index, :show, :update, :destroy, :create]   do
  collection do
    get :home
    get :about_us
    get :faq
    get :discounts
    get :services
    get :contact_us
    get :admin
    get :posts
  end
end
resources :users
resources :abouts
resources :sessions
resources :coupons
resources :monthly_posts
resources :reviews
resources :categories do
collection { post :sort }
resources :children, :controller => :categories, :only => [:index, :new, :create,   :new_subcategory]
end
resources :products do
  member do
    put :move_up
    put :move_down
  end 
end
resources :faqs do
  collection { post :sort }
end 
root :to => 'sites#home'
match "/savesort" => 'sites#savesort'

end

match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
```

But as of right now, it redirects to /en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/sites/admin (adds en until browser complains).

Any thoughts why it keeps adding /en?

**Edit:**
The answer is great, thanks. Can you help me diagnose the root route?

```
root to: redirect("#{/#{I18n.default_locale}") # handles /
```

I know redirects is looking for something like

```
redirect("www.example.com")
```

So that leaves this part

```
#{/#{I18n.default_locale}
```

The #{ is using rubys string interpolation, right? i'm not sure what that { is doing though.

So then we have

```
/#{I18n.default_locale}
```

Which is also using string interpolation and to print out the value of I18n.default_locale?

Hopefully that makes sense, I really really appreciate the help, I am learning a lot.

**Edit 2:**

I changed the line from

```
root to: redirect("#{/#{I18n.default_locale}") # handles /
```

to

```
root to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}") # handles /
```

But i'm not sure if thats right. Now i'm getting the error

```
uninitialized constant LocaleController
```

I know it's getting the error from the root to: "locale#root", but i thought the locale# would come from the scope.

I'll continue playing with it and let you know any progress.

Here is a new link to my routes file https://gist.github.com/2332198

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We meet again, ruevaughn. :)

I created a test rails app and the following minimal example works for me:

```
scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  resources :sites do
    collection do
      get :admin
    end
  end

  root to: "locale#root" # handles /en/
  match "*path", to: "locale#not_found" # handles /en/fake/path/whatever
end

root to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}") # handles /
match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}") # handles /not-a-locale/anything
```

Comment: And am I sure glad we did meet again :) The answer is more than I could have hoped for. I didn't know you could have a root to: in your scope AND outside of it, and I was unaware I could call locale#root like that. I am still learning.  The root to: redirect I am not quite sure about so I posted an edit in the question if you have time. Thanks again

Comment: `locale#root` is a short form for `controller#action`, so that would be to the LocaleController's `root` method. I used that just as a placeholder; you can replace it with whatever makes sense in your app.

Comment: Ah, and to answer your edit, that was a typo ^_^ Sorry about that! I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using Rails 4.0.x that `%{path}` in the redirect will escape slashes in the path, so you will get an infinite loop redirecting to `/en/en%2Fen%2Fen%2Fen...`

Just in case someone, like me, is looking for a Rails-4-suitable solution, this is what I found to be working without problems, even with more complex paths to be redirected:

```
# Redirect root to /:locale if needed
root to: redirect("/#{I18n.locale}", status: 301)

# Match missing locale paths to /:locale/path
# handling additional formats and/or get params
match '*path', to: (redirect(status: 307) do |params,request|
  sub_params = request.params.except :path
  if sub_params.size > 0
    format = sub_params[:format]
    sub_params.except! :format
    if format.present?
      "/#{I18n.locale}/#{params[:path]}.#{format}?#{sub_params.to_query}"
    else
      "/#{I18n.locale}/#{params[:path]}?#{sub_params.to_query}"
    end
  else
    "/#{I18n.locale}/#{params[:path]}"
  end
end), via: :all

# Redirect to custom root if all previous matches fail
match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.locale}", status: 301), via: :all
```

Comment: I'm still getting the problem even after replacing old code with yours. please advise

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code I am currently using in a production environment. Never ever had problems for about a year now. Let me know if this works for you @Sai!

Comment: Thanks, that did work for me. I was having issues with assets precompile which I thought was also caused by this