# I18n and redirecting in Ruby on Rails causes some issues

Tags: internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I saw a "railscasts" cast and did like them told me. Here is a part of my route.rb

```
  scope ':locale', :locale=> /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    #..........
    #..........
    namespace :admin do
      resources :products do
         get :who_bought, :on=>:member
     end
     end
  end

  match '*path', :to=> redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
  match '', :to=> redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
```

Because of this, some issues are caused now. Look at my log.

```
Started GET "/products/4/who_bought.atom" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 09:58:35 +0400
2012-08-31 09:58:35 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/products/4/who_bought" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 09:58:35 +0400
2012-08-31 09:58:35 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/products/4/who_bought" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 09:58:35 +0400
2012-08-31 09:58:35 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/products/4/who_bought" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 09:58:35 +0400
2012-08-31 09:58:35 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/products/4/who_bought" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 09:58:35 +0400
2012-08-31 09:58:35 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/en/products/4/who_bought" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 09:58:35 +0400
2012-08-31 09:58:35 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/en/en/products/4/who_bought" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 09:58:35 +0400
2012-08-31 09:58:35 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/products/4/who_bought" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 09:58:35 +0400
```

or

```
Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:36 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:36 INFO -- Served asset /logo.png - 404 Not Found (13ms)
2012-08-31 10:55:36 INFO -- 

Started GET "/assets/products/tea1.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:36 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:36 INFO -- Served asset /products/tea1.jpg - 404 Not Found (2ms)
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/assets/logo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/assets/products/tea1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/assets/logo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/assets/products/tea1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/assets/logo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/assets/products/tea1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/assets/logo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/assets/products/tea1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/en/assets/logo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/en/assets/products/tea1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/en/en/assets/logo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/en/en/assets/products/tea1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/assets/logo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/assets/products/tea1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO -- 

Started GET "/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/assets/logo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-31 10:55:38 +0400
2012-08-31 10:55:38 INFO --
```

If I go to `"http://localhost:3000/en/fdsfdsfdsfds"` it will redirect me to `"http://localhost:3000/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/fdsfdsfdsfds"`

I want to get rid off that. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not handling scoped requests to invalid resources. Your app redirects a request by adding a locale to it, but if there is nothing to match it in the locale block then it continues down and reaches the `match` catch-all line, appending another locale to it, ad infinitum.

You need to add another catch-all line *inside* the scope block *after* you declare the resources, like this:

```
scope ':locale', :locale=> /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do

  ...

  namespace :admin do
    resources :products do
      get :who_bought, :on=>:member
   end
  end

  root to: "locale#root"
  match "*path", to: "locale#not_found"
end

match '*path', :to=> redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
match '', :to=> redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
```

In the cases you've presented, the request URL does not match any resources because you've namespaced your resources under `admin`, so you need to access them at URLs that have the prefix `/en/admin/`, `/es/admin/` etc.

See also: [Why rails app is redirecting unexpectedly instead of matching the route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052158/why-rails-app-is-redirecting-unexpectedly-instead-of-matching-the-route)

Comment: What does `*path` and `/%{path}` mean? And should I replace `"locale#not_found"` with the path I want to handle 404?

Comment: `*path` matches any non-empty string and captures it, and puts it into the redirect at `%{path}`. So `/no/match` will match with `path` set to the whole string, and will redirect to `/en/no/match`. See: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/17658146816/wildcards-in-rails-redirects . And yes, I didn't mention but you should replace "locale#not_found" with the controller/action you want to use to handle a 404.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be with your routes file (assuming you do not redirect elsewhere). Try changing the last bit to:

```
root to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}") 
match '*path', :to => redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
```

And perhaps remove the call elsewhere to

```
puts "INFO...
```

which is cluttering up your logs.